# Getting _CXX0X_WARNING_H in XCode when I compile code with GCC 5.3

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, gcc

I use this Plugin in `XCode` for turning on `GCC 5.3`: https://github.com/hmazhar/xcode-gcc/blob/master/GCC%205.2.xcplugin/Contents/Resources/GCC%205.2.xcspec
I've replaced all 5.2 with 5.3 and have installed GCC 5.3 with brew on my OS X.

Then I changed `Compiler for C/C++/Objective-C` to my `GCC 5.3` but when I try to compile `C++` code I get following message. Where should I change settings?

```
#ifndef _CXX0X_WARNING_H
#define _CXX0X_WARNING_H 1

#if __cplusplus < 201103L
#error This file requires compiler and library support for the \
ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be \
enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
#endif

#endif
```

Xcode 7.2, OS X El Captain 10.11.3, GCC 5.3.

**Outdated:** 
- it doesn't work.

*Following some articles to enabling GCC 4.5 I haven't done only this step:*

> 2)In the project settings
>
> delete “CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY" row
>   I don't know to remove it. I should empty value of this variable or should I remove it entirely? Can it be the root of my problem?

Comment: Well try delete the reference to clang first. Any reference to another compiler is not going to sit well with your compiler.

Comment: Looks like the `-std=c++11` flag is not being passed to the compiler. Is there a place to add compiler flags?

Comment: @CarefulNow, finally I removed that option but nothing changes. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Is there a chance to see the building command and GCC options with which Xcode trying to build my project?